# Pan Gesture to move SKScene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a question.

I have a `SKScene` in which I want the user to be able to move it with a `UIPanGesture` and when the user stops panning, I want the `SKScene` to have a ease out smooth animation.

If you have played Clash of Clans, you will be familiarised with this. Is the same animation as when you pan navigate through your home village.

Which could be the best way to achieve this?

And how can I add boundaries to it, for it to stop moving when it reaches a certain point in the view?

Comment: You will need a `UIScrollView` I believe with some gesture recognizers. I will see if I can find how to do so.

Comment: Your question is too broad.